# Is there another way to access Hololens LocalAppData other than the Windows Device Portal?

Tags: hololens, appdata

I keep running into this issue where when I try to save local app files from a Hololens to my computer via the Windows Device Portal, the Portal takes forever to download them and eventually times out. This is frustrating since I have no problem connecting to the Portal otherwise, and the files I'm trying to download are super small. Does anyone know of another way I can access these files?

[WDP shows that it's waiting on the IP address for minutes before losing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHH0S.png)

Answer (score 0):

How did you connect your HoloLens to the PC? With Wi-Fi or USB? To check if there are connectivity issues in your network, it is recommended that you try another connection method to access the Device Portal by following this doc:[Using the Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal). If the behavior still occurs, please open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I had the Hololens connected via USB yet was using the Device Portal as if I were connect remotely. To solve my issue, I had to use the address http://127.0.0.1:10080/ rather than the Hololens IP.