# Cannot download files from device portal in hololens2

Tags: hololens

I'm trying to download a video rom the device portal I shot with the hololens app , but the file doesn't download when I select [save].

The state is similar to the example below but I am connected via wifi and connect to the device portal from the IP address of the hololens.

[Is there another way to access Hololens LocalAppData other than the Windows Device Portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645608/is-there-another-way-to-access-hololens-localappdata-other-than-the-windows-devi)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-troubleshooting#device-portal-file-uploaddownload-times-out), and we're working hard to address these and have root caused most of them, with fixes being prepared for a device OS update. Besides, Firefox will work for some people, but it is not a reliable workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download your video via Webbrowser or via the software Microsoft Hololens.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-troubleshooting#device-portal-file-uploaddownload-times-out). This worked for me on Chrome.

Workaround
This workaround, which applies equally to Wi-Fi and UsbNcm, is to disable the "required" option under "SSL Connection". To do so, navigate to Device Portal, System, and select the Preferences page. In the Device Security section, locate SSL Connection, and uncheck to disable Required.

The user should then go to http://, not https:// (IP address) and features like file upload and download will work.